# Fetch category wise data from database table with limit

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch 2 rows of each category from a single table where I have category also mentioned. When I try to fetch data using GROUP BY Clause, I am able to get 1 row for each type of category, but I want two rows. How can I achieve that result.

For example

| id | name         | category |

| 1  | orange       | fruits   |

| 2  | mango        | fruits   |

| 3  | cherry       | fruits   |

| 4  | potato       | veggie   |

| 5  | onion        | veggie   |

| 6  | pumpkin      | veggie   |

| 7  | basil        | herbs    |

| 8  | black pepper | herbs    |

| 9  | cloves       | herbs    |

[Table example image, please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd5aw.png)

I want to fetch first two rows of each category.

Since my mysql version is 5.7, I cannot use window commands as  suggested in the answer, though it may be correct, but not for my version.

Edit: With solution which is posted by @jared.

[Solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udf6d.png)

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think window functions is what you want here:

```
-- Asuming your table is named 'food'
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category) AS category_row_index 
    FROM `food` 
) food_catgorized 
    WHERE 
        food_catgorized.category_row_index BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

UPD: following query should work with MySql 5.7:

```
-- Asuming your table is named 'food'
SELECT food.* FROM food 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
        FROM `food` 
        GROUP BY category
) category_ids
ON 
    food.category = category_ids.category
WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET(food.id, category_ids.ids) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not working. It gives error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY category) AS category_row_index FROM food) food_catgorized  WHERE food_catgorized.category_row_index at line 1

Comment: I figured out that I have mysql version 5.7, which doesn't support Window functions. Maybe your answer is correct for higher version, do you have any solution for Mysql version 5.7

Comment: If upgrading to the modern version is not an option, here's an [article](https://dev.to/maxborysov/mysql-5-7-window-function-workaround-1h76) that might help finding a workaround.

Comment: is there a way to run a loop for each category in where clause and fetch two rows based on that? @jared

Comment: I've rewritten the query and updated the answer. I don't have a 5.7 by my hand, please check if the query works for you.

Comment: its completely awesome. works perfectly, will just remove one category from result because it is showing it two times. Awesome, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont know why would somebody give negative vote to question. I had to ask to get the solution and @Jared gave it perfectly.